# Unicode String Encoding Python

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

I have tried using the code made available by wassname at the following address https://gist.github.com/wassname/5b10774dfcd61cdd3f28

I have a question regarding the last part of the code (below). The resulting csv file contains unicode characters, but they are not the intended characters in German that I need to use. Python console does recognize the characters, but when I open up the csv files, I have to convert the file to 65001 unicode to observe the intended characters. Is there any way to adjust the code so as to skip the additional csv step?

Thanks

```
    page=os.path.split(wiki)[1]
fname='output_{}_t{}.csv'.format(page,tn)
f = codecs.open(fname, 'w', encoding='utf-8')    
for i in range(nrows):
    rowStr=','.join(data[i])
    rowStr=rowStr.replace('\n','')
    print(rowStr)
    rowStr=rowStr#.encode('unicode_escape')
    f.write(rowStr+ '\n')      


f.close()
```

Comment: It seems a question for superuser. You wrote that python write the file correctly in Unicode, and if you open with unicode (so 65001) you get the correct characters. So you should check on superuser how to make your program to open automatically the file as unicode (Microsoft use a header line on csv files, but not always consistent, and we need to know the program)

Comment: I think you are right. I "should check on superuser how to make your program to open automatically the file as unicode". I was opening up the csv files with Office 365 - Excel.